# How to verify checksum file of centos 8?

Tags: linux, centos, gpg, checksum

How to verify that the CHECKSUM file for the CentOS 8 ISO is real?

Download check sum and key:

```
$ wget https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official
$ wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/centos/8.0.1905/isos/x86_64/CHECKSUM
$ wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/centos/8.0.1905/isos/x86_64/CHECKSUM.asc
```

Verify Key:

```
$ gpg RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official 

gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa4096 2019-05-03 [SC]
      99DB70FAE1D7CE227FB6488205B555B38483C65D
uid           CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>

Assert that the fingerprint matches https://www.centos.org/keys/
```

import key:

```
$ gpg --import RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official
gpg: key 05B555B38483C65D: public key "CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Cannot verify the CHECKSUM file:

```
$ gpg --verify CHECKSUM.asc

gpg: Signature made Mon 23 Sep 2019 07:24:37 AM EDT
gpg:                using RSA key 05B555B38483C65D
gpg: Good signature from "CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 99DB 70FA E1D7 CE22 7FB6  4882 05B5 55B3 8483 C65D
gpg: WARNING: not a detached signature; file 'CHECKSUM' was NOT verified!
```

It says:

```
 gpg: WARNING: not a detached signature; file 'CHECKSUM' was NOT verified!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need both `CHECKSUM` and `CHECKSUM.asc`.  The latter is GPG-signed version of `CHECKSUM`.  GPG is confused because it assumes that if you have `somefilename` and `somefilename.asc`, that the `.asc` file is a detached signature.

If you delete the file `CHECKSUM`, then you can `gpg --verify CHECKSUM.asc` and get:

```
gpg: Signature made Mon 23 Sep 2019 07:24:37 AM EDT
gpg:                using RSA key 0x05B555B38483C65D
gpg: Good signature from "CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 99DB 70FA E1D7 CE22 7FB6  4882 05B5 55B3 8483 C65D
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem here in fedora 34 workstation (host).

```
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$ ll
total 741388
-rw-r--r--. 1 chris chris 759169024 Jun  5 11:46 CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso
-rw-r--r--. 1 chris chris       355 Jun  5 15:15 CHECKSUM
-rw-r--r--. 1 chris chris       811 Jun  5 15:17 CHECKSUM.asc
-rw-r--r--. 1 chris chris      1683 Jun  5 17:30 RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$
```

Remember that the pgp-signature files like CHECKSUM.asc is generate by another file.
I suppose the procedure of the Centos team was approximately the following.

```
sha256sum CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.img > CHECKSUM

gpg --sign --armor CHECKSUM
```

The above commands generates both files `CHECKSUM` and `CHECKSUM.asc`.

This [page has a useful guide, verify fedora images](https://getfedora.org/security/)

---

Steps to verify:

First you need to [import the keys](https://www.centos.org/keys/), click in the download link, then CTRL + save.

[image]

Then import.

```
gpg --import RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official
```

Then verify that the CHECKSUM file is valid, here you need the following both files

- CHECKSUM
- CHECKSUM.asc

Verify with the following commands

```
gpg --verify CHECKSUM.asc
```

```
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$ gpg --verify CHECKSUM.asc 
gpg: assuming signed data in 'CHECKSUM'
gpg: Signature made Thu 03 Jun 2021 01:58:15 AM -05
gpg:                using RSA key 05B555B38483C65D
gpg: Good signature from "CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 99DB 70FA E1D7 CE22 7FB6  4882 05B5 55B3 8483 C65D
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$
```

The importan line is This

```
gpg: Good signature from "CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>" [unknown]
```

All is ok.

**Now and lastly**

Verify the hash number of the Centos image file downloaded match with the hash number inside the `CHECKSUM` file. Remember that the `CHECKSUM` file can have inside multiple hash numbers of the different versions, in this case there are 2 versions

[image]

You can do it in multiples ways.

**First way:**

Run the following command.

```
sha256sum CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso
```

```
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$ sha256sum CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso 
6d957521b4488fc44bb80bdcb618bc1cf9891a997fdbd94e22424c14a356cf09  CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$
```

And compare this hash number `6d957521b4488fc44bb80bdcb618bc1cf9891a997fdbd94e22424c14a356cf09` with the one inside the CHECKSUM file in the corresponding line of the image, the hash numbers must match each other.

[image]

As you can see, the hash numbers matches.

**Second way:**

Run the following command.
Select the hash number inside the CHECKSUM file copy and paste there after `grep` command.

```
sha256sum CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso | grep paste-here-the-hash-number
```

[image]

If the color is red all is ok, It means both matches.

**Third way**

The easiest way, both files are neccesary.

- CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso
- CHECKSUM

Run the follwing command

```
sha256sum -c CHECKSUM
```

```
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$ sha256sum -c CHECKSUM
CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso: OK
sha256sum: CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-dvd1.iso: No such file or directory
CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-dvd1.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
[chris@f34 verify-centos]$
```

As we can see in there say ok

```
CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20210603-boot.iso: OK
```

End.